# Rails current visitor count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, visitor-statistic

How does one implement a current visitors count for individual pages in Rails?

For example, a property website has a list of properties and a remark that says:-
"there are 6 people currently looking at this property" for each individual listing.

I'm aware of the impressionist gem, which is able to log unique impressions for each controller. Just wondering if there is a better way than querying

```
impressions.where("created_at <= ?", 5.minutes.ago).count
```

for each object in the array.

Comment: I don't think this query would return what you want - an impression can be created 5 minutes ago but the user still be watching your content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you get downvoted, I'll give you an idea of how to do it

Recording visitors is in the realm of [analytics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytics), of which Google Analytics is the most popular & recognized

---

**Analytics**

Analytics systems work with 3 parts:

- Capture
- Processing
- Display

The process of capturing & processing data is fundamentally the same -- put a JS widget on your site to send a query to the server with attached user data. Processing the data puts it into your database

---

**Displaying The Data**

The difference for many people is the display of the data they capture

- Google Analytics displays the data in their dashboard
- Ebay displays the data as `x people bought in the past hour`
- You want to show the number of people viewing an item

The way to do this is to hard-code the processing aspect of the data into your app

I can't explain the exact way to do this, because it's highly dependent on your stack, but this is the general way to do it

Comment: Thanks Rich! I've only started programming about 6 months ago and this is all still new to me. Many thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: I'm aware of Google Analytics (vaguely). Just wondering if there is a Rails way of tracking current visitor count so I can minimize external dependencies.

Comment: I only gave GA as an example of how it would work. You have the choice of rolling your own analytics (something we're involved with right now -- can tell you more about the programming if interested), or using one of the off-the-shelf systems out there

Comment: How's the programming going after 6 months?

Comment: Excruciating! But extremely rewarding. I don't know what I would do if it wasn't for Stackoverflow!